# Cannot generate PyTorch ObjectDetector model

Tags: pytorch

[Failed prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyghW.jpg)I am having a devil of a time trying to train a model. I am a noob to machine learning, although I do have lots of programming experience (new to python, though).

I am following the tutorial at
https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/11/01/training-an-object-detector-from-scratch-in-pytorch/
I basically copied their code, then modified for my purposes.

The problem: The model "appears" to train, although I have no way to verify this.
Unfortunately, the prediction code runs but does not work. It always gives a single prediction bounding box instead of the expected multiple boxes. The box is never on an object; it is randomly sized, never the size of an object on the screen.

My first problem is to figure out which is wrong - the trained model or the prediction code.

I will attach an image of the results of a training run, and a copy of the screen messages.
The training loss seems to drop appropriately. Maybe the validation loss is OK? However,
I naively expect the accuracy to increase instead of staying constant at 99%.

I will also attach an image of a prediction run. In this particular image (from the training
set) I hope to see 4 objects: 3 balls (a small one is on the fence) and the ball machine.
Instead, I see a single ball detection of random size and location.

The model is supposed to detect 3 classes:
a ball, the ball machine, and the net. There are several hundred training detections of a
ball, around 50 of the ball machine, and only a few of the net. I will get more images later - I do not expect the ball machine and net to detect correctly right now.
I use the resnet50 model only because the tutorial used it. If I ever get this model to work
I hope to move to fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2 or an sdd model.

I am running on Windows 10 since my laptop is moderately fast (Quadcore i7). It has an Nvidia GPU,but the system is using cpu. PyTorch is a recently loaded current version; Python is 3.11. I am using venv to install things. Eventually I hope to run the model on a Raspberry Pi.

==============================================================================
Here is the config.py file used by both the train and predict:

```
#  pyimagesearch/config.py 

# import the necessary packages
import torch
import os
# define the base path to the input dataset and then use it to derive
# the path to the input images and annotation CSV files
BASE_PATH = "D:/Dropbox/CoolStuff/Pickleball/BallChaser/images/TensorFlow/TrainingSteps/PyT1/datasetChop"
IMAGES_PATH = os.path.sep.join([BASE_PATH, "ChunkImage"])
ANNOTS_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "ChunkImage")
# define the path to the base output directory
BASE_OUTPUT = os.path.sep.join([BASE_PATH, "output"]) 
# define the path to the output model, label encoder, plots output
# directory, and testing image paths
MODEL_PATH = os.path.sep.join([BASE_OUTPUT, "detector.pth"])
LE_PATH = os.path.sep.join([BASE_OUTPUT, "le.pickle"])
PLOTS_PATH = os.path.sep.join([BASE_OUTPUT, "plots"])
TEST_PATHS = os.path.sep.join([BASE_OUTPUT, "test_paths.txt"])


# determine the current device and based on that set the pin memory
# flag
DEVICE = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
PIN_MEMORY = True if DEVICE == "cuda" else False
# specify ImageNet mean and standard deviation
# channel, width, height values
MEAN = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
STD = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
# initialize our initial learning rate, number of epochs to train
# for, and the batch size
INIT_LR = 5e-4    
NUM_EPOCHS = 20
BATCH_SIZE = 32  # 32
# specify the loss weights
LABELS = 1.0
BBOX = 1.0

#=========================================================================
# parameters for other programs:
#   labelme2voc.py
#   ChopImageXML.py
#   SplitClassAndCsv.py
#From above, BASE_PATH is the dataset name 

CHOP_INPUT_FOLDER = os.path.join(BASE_PATH,'me2vocOutput','JPEGImages')     # OrigImages
CHOP_OUTPUT_FOLDER = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'ChunkImage') 
CHOP_OUTPUT_DET_FOLDER = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'ChunkImage', 'Detections') 
CHOP_CLASS_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH,'labelmap.txt')

SPLIT_INPUT_JPG_FOLDER = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'ChunkImage')     # OrigImages
SPLIT_CLASS_NAMES_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH,'labelmap.txt')
SPLIT_TOTAL_CSV_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'ChunkImage','total.csv')
SPLIT_CLASS_OUTPUT_FOLDER = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'ChunkImage')
```

==============================================================================
Here is the prediction code:

```
# predict.py
# USAGE
# python predict.py --input dataset/images/face/image_0131.jpg
# import the necessary packages
from pyimagesearch import config
from torchvision import transforms
import mimetypes
import argparse
import imutils
import pickle
import torch
import cv2

print('imports done')
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True,
    help="path to input image/text file of image paths")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# determine the input file type, but assume that we're working with
# single input image
filetype = mimetypes.guess_type(args["input"])[0]
imagePaths = [args["input"]]

# if the file type is a text file, then we need to process *multiple*
# images
if "text/plain" == filetype:
    # load the image paths in our testing file
    imagePaths = open(args["input"]).read().strip().split("\n")
    
# load our object detector, set it evaluation mode, and label
# encoder from disk
print("[INFO] loading object detector...")
model = torch.load(config.MODEL_PATH).to(config.DEVICE)
model.eval()
le = pickle.loads(open(config.LE_PATH, "rb").read())

# define normalization transforms
transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToPILImage(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=config.MEAN, std=config.STD)
])

# loop over the images that we'll be testing using our bounding box
# regression model
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # load the image, copy it, swap its colors channels, resize it, and
    # bring its channel dimension forward
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    orig = image.copy()
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
    image = image.transpose((2, 0, 1))
    
    # convert image to PyTorch tensor, normalize it, flash it to the
    # current device, and add a batch dimension
    image = torch.from_numpy(image)
    image = transforms(image).to(config.DEVICE)
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)
    
    # predict the bounding box of the object along with the class
    # label
    (boxPreds, labelPreds) = model(image)
    print('LabelPreds Shape: ', labelPreds.shape)
    print('LabelPreds: ',labelPreds)
    print('boxPreds shape: ', boxPreds.shape)
    print('boxPreds: ', boxPreds)
    (startX, startY, endX, endY) = boxPreds[0]
    
    # determine the class label with the largest predicted
    # probability
    labelPreds = torch.nn.Softmax(dim=-1)(labelPreds)
    print('torch Softmax labelPreds: ', labelPreds.shape)
    print(labelPreds)
    i = labelPreds.argmax(dim=-1).cpu()
    label = le.inverse_transform(i)[0]
    
    # resize the original image such that it fits on our screen, and
    # grab its dimensions
    orig = imutils.resize(orig, width=600)
    (h, w) = orig.shape[:2]
    
    # scale the predicted bounding box coordinates based on the image
    # dimensions
    startX = int(startX * w)
    startY = int(startY * h)
    endX = int(endX * w)
    endY = int(endY * h)
    
    # draw the predicted bounding box and class label on the image
    y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
    cv2.putText(orig, label, (startX, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.65, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(orig, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
        (0, 255, 0), 2)
    
    # show the output image 
    cv2.imshow("Output", orig)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

========================================================================
and here is the training code

```
# train.py
# USAGE
# python train.py
# import the necessary packages
import cv2
from pyimagesearch.bbox_regressor import ObjectDetector
from pyimagesearch.custom_tensor_dataset import CustomTensorDataset
from pyimagesearch import config
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.nn import CrossEntropyLoss
from torch.nn import MSELoss
from torch.optim import Adam
from torchvision.models import resnet50, ResNet50_Weights
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from imutils import paths
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pickle
import torch
import time
import os

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKRED  = '\033[91m'
    OKYELLOW = '\033[93m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'


# initialize the list of data (images), class labels, target bounding
# box coordinates, and image paths
print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}[INFO] Device is {config.DEVICE}{bcolors.ENDC}")
print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}[INFO] loading dataset...{bcolors.ENDC}")
data = []
labels = []                 
bboxes = []
imagePaths = []

# loop over all CSV files in the annotations directory
#for csvPath in paths.list_files(config.ANNOTS_PATH, validExts=(".csv")):
csvPath = os.path.join(config.ANNOTS_PATH, 'total.csv')
# load the contents of the current CSV annotations file
rows = open(csvPath).read().strip().split("\n")

# loop over the rows
for row in rows:
    # break the row into the filename, bounding box coordinates,
    # and class label
    row = row.split(",")
    (filename, startX, startY, endX, endY, label) = row
    
    # derive the path to the input image, load the image (in
    # OpenCV format), and grab its dimensions
    imagePath = os.path.sep.join([config.IMAGES_PATH, filename])  #label, filename])
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    
    # scale the bounding box coordinates relative to the spatial
    # dimensions of the input image
    startX = float(startX) / w
    startY = float(startY) / h
    endX = float(endX) / w
    endY = float(endY) / h
    
    # load the image and preprocess it
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
    
    # update our list of data, class labels, bounding boxes, and
    # image paths
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(label)
    bboxes.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))
    imagePaths.append(imagePath)

#debug
print(f'{bcolors.OKRED}num data is {len(data)}{bcolors.ENDC}')      
print(f'{bcolors.OKRED}num labels is {len(labels)}{bcolors.ENDC}')      
print(f'{bcolors.OKRED}num bboxes is {len(bboxes)}{bcolors.ENDC}')      
print(f'{bcolors.OKRED}num imagePaths is {len(imagePaths)}{bcolors.ENDC}')  
    
# convert the data, class labels, bounding boxes, and image paths to
# NumPy arrays
print(f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Creating Numpy arrays{bcolors.ENDC}')
data = np.array(data, dtype="float32")
labels = np.array(labels)
print(f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Starting labels...{bcolors.ENDC}')
print(labels)
bboxes = np.array(bboxes, dtype="float32")
imagePaths = np.array(imagePaths)

# perform label encoding on the labels
print(f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Label Encoding{bcolors.ENDC}')
le = LabelEncoder()
labels = le.fit_transform(labels)
print(f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Encoded labels...{bcolors.ENDC}')
print(labels)

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 80% of
# the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing
print(f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Partitioning into training and testing data{bcolors.ENDC}')
split = train_test_split(data, labels, bboxes, imagePaths,
    test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

# unpack the data split
(trainImages, testImages) = split[:2]
(trainLabels, testLabels) = split[2:4]
(trainBBoxes, testBBoxes) = split[4:6]
(trainPaths, testPaths) = split[6:]

# convert NumPy arrays to PyTorch tensors
print(f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Converting into PyTorch tensors{bcolors.ENDC}')
(trainImages, testImages) = torch.tensor(trainImages),\
    torch.tensor(testImages)
(trainLabels, testLabels) = torch.tensor(trainLabels),\
    torch.tensor(testLabels)
(trainBBoxes, testBBoxes) = torch.tensor(trainBBoxes),\
    torch.tensor(testBBoxes)

# define normalization transforms
print (f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Define normalization transforms{bcolors.ENDC}')
transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToPILImage(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=config.MEAN, std=config.STD)
])

# convert NumPy arrays to PyTorch datasets
print(f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Convert NumPy arrays to PyTorch datasets{bcolors.ENDC}')
trainDS = CustomTensorDataset((trainImages, trainLabels, trainBBoxes),
    transforms=transforms)
testDS = CustomTensorDataset((testImages, testLabels, testBBoxes),
    transforms=transforms)
#print(f'[INFO] total training samples: {0:4d}...'.format(len(trainDS)))
#print(f"[INFO] total test samples:     {0:4d}...".format(len(testDS)))
print(f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}[INFO] total training samples: {len(trainDS):4d}{bcolors.ENDC}')
print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}[INFO] total test samples:     {len(testDS):4d}{bcolors.ENDC}")

# calculate steps per epoch for training and validation set
trainSteps = len(trainDS) // config.BATCH_SIZE
valSteps = len(testDS) // config.BATCH_SIZE

# create data loaders
print(f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Create data loaders{bcolors.ENDC}')
trainLoader = DataLoader(trainDS, batch_size=config.BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=True, num_workers=0,  # os.cpu_count(), 
    pin_memory=config.PIN_MEMORY)
testLoader = DataLoader(testDS, batch_size=config.BATCH_SIZE,
    num_workers=0,   # os.cpu_count(), 
    pin_memory=config.PIN_MEMORY)

# write the testing image paths to disk so that we can use then
# when evaluating/testing our object detector
print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}[INFO] saving testing image paths...{bcolors.ENDC}")
f = open(config.TEST_PATHS, "w")
f.write("\n".join(testPaths))
f.close()

# load the ResNet50 network
#  Want to try ssd300_vgg16 and fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2
print(f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Loading ResNet50 network{bcolors.ENDC}')
resnet = resnet50(weights=ResNet50_Weights.DEFAULT)       # old (pretrained=True)

# freeze all ResNet50 layers so they will *not* be updated during the
# training process
for param in resnet.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

# create our custom object detector model and flash it to the current
# device
print(f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}Create ObjectDetector{bcolors.ENDC}')
objectDetector = ObjectDetector(resnet, len(le.classes_))
objectDetector = objectDetector.to(config.DEVICE)

# define our loss functions
classLossFunc = CrossEntropyLoss()
bboxLossFunc = MSELoss()

# initialize the optimizer, compile the model, and show the model
# summary
opt = Adam(objectDetector.parameters(), lr=config.INIT_LR)
print(objectDetector)

# initialize a dictionary to store training history
H = {"total_train_loss": [], "total_val_loss": [], "train_class_acc": [],
     "val_class_acc": []}

# loop over epochs
print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}[INFO] training the network...{bcolors.ENDC}")
startTime = time.time()
for e in tqdm(range(config.NUM_EPOCHS)):
    # set the model in training mode
    objectDetector.train()
    
    # initialize the total training and validation loss
    totalTrainLoss = 0
    totalValLoss = 0
    
    # initialize the number of correct predictions in the training
    # and validation step
    trainCorrect = 0
    valCorrect = 0

    # loop over the training set
    for (images, labels, bboxes) in trainLoader:
        # send the input to the device
        (images, labels, bboxes) = (images.to(config.DEVICE),
            labels.to(config.DEVICE), bboxes.to(config.DEVICE))
        
        # perform a forward pass and calculate the training loss
        predictions = objectDetector(images)
        bboxLoss = bboxLossFunc(predictions[0], bboxes)
        classLoss = classLossFunc(predictions[1], labels)
        totalLoss = (config.BBOX * bboxLoss) + (config.LABELS * classLoss)
        
        # zero out the gradients, perform the backpropagation step,
        # and update the weights
        opt.zero_grad()
        totalLoss.backward()
        opt.step()
        
        # add the loss to the total training loss so far and
        # calculate the number of correct predictions
        totalTrainLoss += totalLoss
        trainCorrect += (predictions[1].argmax(1) == labels).type(
            torch.float).sum().item()

    # switch off autograd
    with torch.no_grad():
        # set the model in evaluation mode
        objectDetector.eval()
        
        # loop over the validation set
        for (images, labels, bboxes) in testLoader:
            # send the input to the device
            (images, labels, bboxes) = (images.to(config.DEVICE),
                labels.to(config.DEVICE), bboxes.to(config.DEVICE))
            
            # make the predictions and calculate the validation loss
            predictions = objectDetector(images)
            bboxLoss = bboxLossFunc(predictions[0], bboxes)
            classLoss = classLossFunc(predictions[1], labels)
            totalLoss = (config.BBOX * bboxLoss) + (config.LABELS * classLoss)
            totalValLoss += totalLoss
            
            # calculate the number of correct predictions
            valCorrect += (predictions[1].argmax(1) == labels).type(
                torch.float).sum().item()
    
    # calculate the average training and validation loss
    avgTrainLoss = totalTrainLoss / trainSteps
    avgValLoss = totalValLoss / valSteps
    
    # calculate the training and validation accuracy
    trainCorrect = trainCorrect / len(trainDS)
    valCorrect = valCorrect / len(testDS)
    
    # update our training history
    H["total_train_loss"].append(avgTrainLoss.cpu().detach().numpy())
    H["train_class_acc"].append(trainCorrect)
    H["total_val_loss"].append(avgValLoss.cpu().detach().numpy())
    H["val_class_acc"].append(valCorrect)
    
    # print the model training and validation information
    #print(f"[INFO] EPOCH: {}/{}".format(e + 1, config.NUM_EPOCHS))
    #print(f"Train loss: {:.6f}, Train accuracy: {:.4f}".format(avgTrainLoss, trainCorrect))
    #print(f"Val loss: {:.6f}, Val accuracy: {:.4f}".format(avgValLoss, valCorrect))
    print(f"[INFO] EPOCH: {e + 1}/{config.NUM_EPOCHS}")
    print(f"Train loss: {avgTrainLoss:.6f}, Train accuracy: {trainCorrect:.4f}")
    print(f"Val loss:   {avgValLoss:.6f},   Val accuracy:   {valCorrect:.4f}")
endTime = time.time()
print(f"{bcolors.OKCYAN}[INFO] total time taken to train the model: {endTime - startTime:.2f}s{bcolors.ENDC}")
    
# serialize the model to disk
print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}[INFO] saving object detector model...{bcolors.ENDC}")
torch.save(objectDetector, config.MODEL_PATH)

# serialize the label encoder to disk
print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}[INFO] saving label encoder...{bcolors.ENDC}")
f = open(config.LE_PATH, "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(le))
f.close()

# plot the training loss and accuracy
print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}[INFO] building plots...{bcolors.ENDC}")
plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(H["total_train_loss"], label="total_train_loss")
plt.plot(H["total_val_loss"], label="total_val_loss")
plt.plot(H["train_class_acc"], label="train_class_acc")
plt.plot(H["val_class_acc"], label="val_class_acc")
plt.title("Total Training Loss and Classification Accuracy on Dataset")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend(loc="lower left")

# save the training plot
plotPath = os.path.sep.join([config.PLOTS_PATH, "training.png"])
print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}[INFO] saving training plot as {plotPath}...{bcolors.ENDC}")
plt.savefig(plotPath)
```

[Failed prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dol8v.png)
[Training run results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5A6D.png)